# How can we count the number of vowels in a string in assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

I want to count the number of vowels in an input string, written only in minuscules.
My code is this one, but he doesn't count them right (the `cmp` instructions are never `true`)

```
data segment 
      s db 10 dup(' ')
data ends

code segment 

assume ds:data, cs:code

debut: mov ax,data
mov ds,ax

mov dx,offset s
mov ah,0ah
int 21h

mov cl,s[1] 
mov di,offset s
mov bx,0

nr_vocale: cmp cl,0
je sfarsit
mov al,[di]
cmp al,'a'
je increment
mov al,[di]
cmp al,'e'
je increment
mov al,[di]
cmp al,'i'
je increment
mov al,[di]
cmp al,'o'
je increment
mov al,[di]
cmp al,'u'
je increment
inc di
dec cl


increment:  inc bx
 sfarsit: mov dl,bl
 mov ah,2
 int 21h

 mov ah,4ch
 int 21h

 ends code
end debut
```

Comment: [User Appreciation Challenge #1: Dennis ♦](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123458) shows how to use a bitmap in a register with `bt` to classify alphabetic characters efficiently.  You just need to count, so `bt` / `adc reg, 0` will work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a loop, just check the first letter in the string then exit.

Also it is strange that you load cl from s[1] as if the length was stored in the string. Or if the length sits there the string data is probably at s[2], that must be reflected in di.

And it is enough to load al once, and just do the cmp instructions.

Comment: thanks, you were right, the s[2] field doesn't store the size of the string. I used the symbol '$' to find the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `s` is your string offset and `$` the string terminator, as per your comment, then you can do:

```
        mov    si,offset s    
        cld                ; Scan forward
        mov    bx,0        ; bx is count of vowels
check:
        lodsb              ; Load string byte DS:SI in AL and increment SI
        cmp    al, '$'     ; Terminator?
        je     finished
;;      or     al, 20h     ; Set string to lower case (optional)
        cmp    al, 'a'     
        je     increment
        cmp    al, 'e'     
        je     increment
        cmp    al, 'i'     
        je     increment
        cmp    al, 'o'     
        je     increment
        cmp    al, 'u'     
        je     increment
increment:
        inc bx
        jmp    check       ; repeat
finished:
        ;; BX holds the number of vowels.
```

Comment: `int 21h/0Ah` is not going to return a $-terminated string. Probably terminated with 13 (decimal) - carriage return. The count (after the interrupt) is in `s[1]` - use either to find the end of the string. Before the interrupt, `s[0]` is the maximum to get. Since the string is initialized with spaces, this will be 32... into a 10 byte buffer. Not good! (but it probably won't hurt ya) At the end, putting a number in dl is not going to print the number. Doing `add dl, '0'`will print a single-digit number... which may be enough...

Comment: to put the '$' at the end of the string, I used this code:          mov di,offset s[2] ;points to the real beginning of the string
mov bx, di;
add bl, s[1]   ;point right after the string (s pos + s size)
mov [bx], '$'

Comment: Ah! Okay then it is $-terminated! My mistake.

Comment: These branches all fall through to `increment` anyway.  You need something like making the last one  `jne check` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will count vowels

```
countvowels:                     
mov di,VOWL                     
mov si,STR                      
mov bp,di                       
mov cx,END                      
mov bx,STR                      
sub cx,bx             ;stringlength for loop          
dec cx                ;adjust for cx looping         
push cx               ;saved for repeating          
sub si,1              ;tweak si          

nextletter:                      
inc si                          
mov al,[si]                     

vowelrotate:                     
cmp al,[di]                     
jz addone                       
loop nextletter                 
inc di                ;vowel pointer rotate at end of string          
mov si,STR-1          ;return to start of string          
pop cx                ;loop count for string          
push cx                         
mov ah,"x"            ;check for end of vowels           
cmp [di],ah                     
jz finished                     
jmp nextletter                  

addone:                ;vowel count          
inc dx                          
jmp nextletter                  

finished:                        
##                              

VOWL                            
db "aeioux"                     
STR                             
db "input string from keyboard"         
END
```

Comment: Really tempted to downvote for how messy, inefficient, and hard to understand this is (partly because of bad formatting and bad choices for where to (not) leave a blank line), but I think this will actually work.  Looping over the input string once for each vowel, but not keeping the current vowel in a register.